# child process in node is not getting the correct PID id

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

while i trying to spawn a batch file am not getting the correct `PID` of that `child proces`s.

when i tried to kill the `PID` of the child process ,the running process is not stoping and it stops another `cmd`

i dont know how it is happening.

in my batch file am doing to open another `cmd` and change the directry to `C:\AppiumForWindows-1.0.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin` and run a `node` process `node appium`

.i want to execute that `node` process in seperate `cmd` (While spawning that `batch` file it will execute with the same script .i don't need that.)that's what i use separate cmd.

Am confusing due this reason am not getting the correct `PID` of that process?i don't know...

```
var startappium = function (dev, callback) {
  var ports = {};
  var execCmd = __dirname+"//Start.bat"; 

   var args = ['1000']; 
   var start = spawn(execCmd, args);
   console.log("pid id----------------------",start.pid)  
   var pid =start.pid 
   start.stdout.on('data', function (d) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    start .kill()    // it does not kill the process
     },5000);   
   console.log(d.toString())
   return callback(null, ports); 
   });
   start.stderr.on('data', function (ta) {  
      return callback(null, ta); 
  });
  start.on('close', function (code) {  
     console.log("close: ",code)
  });
}
startappium()
```

`Start.bat` file

```
@echo off
start cmd /k " call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat" & pushd C:\AppiumForWindows-1.0.0\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin && node appium -p %1 --chromedriver-port %2" 
pause
```

while running `tasklist` it shows cms with several `PID`'s and i tried to kill one by one and killed that running `batch` file process in one `PID` .

`PID` getting from the child process id not killing the batch process running.
Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't kill a pid as it's an integer. You want to kill the [spawned process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal):

```
start.kill();
```

Comment: yes i used that in my code.i think ur not seen my code.in code that also i mentioned.it does not kill the running process(batch file am running)

Comment: What is the output of all your console logs? Are you sure that the function is not firing more than once?